# What to use for an iOS device motion sensing?

Tags: ios, ipad

I need to detect whether the user is moving the iPad closer / away from him in order to zoom in / out view. What's the best possible way of doing this (most probably using CoreMotion)?

And, if I've already built the project with an external library using CocoaPods. How to add more frameworks if the Link Binary With Libraries now include one item that is libPods.a?

Answer (score 0):

I would use native libraries like core motion.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html

Comment: i wish that was helpful